# Java XMLStreamReader, how to get element text when text contains START_ELEMENT

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, xmlstreamreader

If I have an XML element such as:

```
<title>this is a title</title>
```

The text is very easy to get using XMLStreamReader.`getElementText()`.  However, if I run into an element like this, I cannot figure out how to get the text:

```
<title>this is a <othertag>title with another</othertag> tag inside of it</title>
```

I wasn't even sure if that was valid XML, but it seems to pass the W3C validator I tried it on.  According to [the API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getElementText%28%29), you can't use `getElementText()` to get the text if you are going to encounter another `START_ELEMENT` event inside.  So... what **can** you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [getText](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLStreamReader.html#getText%28%29)

> getText() returns the current value of the parse event as a string,
>   this returns the string value of a CHARACTERS event, returns the value
>   of a COMMENT, the replacement value for an ENTITY_REFERENCE, the
>   string value of a CDATA section, the string value for a SPACE event,
>   or the String value of the internal subset of the DTD. If an
>   ENTITY_REFERENCE has been resolved, any character data will be
>   reported as CHARACTERS events.

Comment: Thanks!  This should have been obvious but my brain was fried after about 16 hours of coding nonstop.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to parse the elements inside the `<title>` tag separately (as `this is a` and then the `<othertag>...</...>` section followed by `tag inside of it`